# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Controlling Dojo Layers

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, dojo

The question concerns how to use the Dojo tooling in Worklight Studio 6.

I am using Worklight Studio 6.0.0.20130926-1933 as a a plugin for my Juno Eclipse on a macbook.

I want to use Dojo, and to use a few more Dojo components than are delivered in the standard layers. So, when creating my project I selected the option to add Dojo Toolkit and took the New Dojo Library option, in the dialogue that appears I stayed with the "provided" dojo, and expanded the "select Dojo components to be included" section - this shows all the optional Dojo modules, including ones I want to use (for example dojox/form/Manager).

Having finished that selection I see some layer files have been created in my new DojoProject and they are copied to the www directory of my Worklight project, however so far as I can see the extra Dojo modules are not present in the layers - a search for dojox/form finds nothing, and my app's attempt to require "dojox/form/Manager" fails.

I can work round this by manually building layers and loading them, but I assume that I'm not using the tool correctly.

What is the correct way to use the Worklight tools to control the layer contents?

Answer (score 0):

Transpires that the selected Dojo components are available for use but do not get included in any layers. The dojo components are available for serving via the Dojo Libarary Requests capability.

Seems that at present if we need to get those extra files into layers then we are required to use the Dojo layer building scripts by hand and copy the results in the Worklight project's wwww directory.